# using LzmaCompress to make an archive

Tags: c, compression, archive, 7zip, lzma

I'm a lil bit confused with compression methods.
I do know how to use this function, and it does output a tinier buffer, but how do I make
an archive using the 7zip sdk, with the compressed data?

i'm quite sure it is a question that is relevant to any compression algorithm.

Comment: are you asking how to make a multiple-file archive? or how to write the compressed data to disk?

Comment: ...or how to compress compressed data?

Comment: i mean , if i take a file, and i compress it into tinier buffers, how do i make it a 7zip file